Why the Homogeneity Assumption?
To derive many relationships between critical exponents, Kardar in chapter 4 of Statistical Physics of Fields introduces an assumption that "going beyond the saddle point, the singular form of the free energy [in a magnet] is
$$f_{\text{sing}}(t,h) = |t|^{2 - \alpha}g_f(h/|t|^\Delta).$$
I havent been able to find a good justification for why this ought to be the case but this assumption has important implications for the renormalization group. Is there a good argument as to why we ought to make this assumption?
